# How can I create two lines from a single line in touchdesigner?

Tags: animation, graphics, touch, visual-programming, generative-art

[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEJLk.jpg)

> I am using SOP, then I render them
>   For the line I used a rectangle, then a transform, and then a material to change it's color
>   I also used an LFO with a NULL to animate the transform in the X axis

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use Geo instancing to create copies.

[Geometry COMP WIKI](https://docs.derivative.ca/Geometry_COMP)

There are some good examples of how do to this in the OP Snippets scene.

[OP Snippets](https://docs.derivative.ca/OP_Snippets)

Comment: @JJJ TouchDesigner is a node based programming environment that uses a Python interface for some actions. In this user's particular case, the most efficient solution is to use the nodes in the interface rather than implementing a solution in Python (which is possible but not preferred).

One solution might be to use a Python OP that manipulates the geometry with an attached callback script, another might be to do it with a C++ TOP compiled in VS. Instancing via the Geo COMP happens on the GPU which is significantly faster than the previously mentioned.